# Text being output when none should be

Tags: expansion, xstring, xparse

I am confused as to why the MWE below produces **any** black text.  As the code is below, the output is:

[image]

However, if you comment out the `\IfStrEq` line then it works fine
and the black text goes away?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GetTexFilePath}{m m m}{%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{SpecialValue}{}{}% this should do nothing
    %
    ../../../#1/#2/#3%
}%

\begin{document}
\def\FileWithPath{\GetTexFilePath{01}{02}{z}}%
\IfFileExists{\FileWithPath}{%
    \textcolor{red}{File \FileWithPath\ found.}%
}{%
    \textcolor{red}{File \FileWithPath\ not found.}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very odd. I tried several things. (1) `\edef\FileWithPath..` same problem. (2) `\def\FileWithPath{...}` problem gone. (3) Using `\FileWithPath` works as expected. The only thing that goes wrong is using `\FileWithPath` and `\IfFileExists` in combination. This may also be related to `xparse`, which is why I added it to the list of keywords.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen file names simply have to expand to characters. It is an expansion problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your problem boils down to the fact that `\IfStrEq` is not expandable, but `\IfFileExist` tries to expand it nevertheless. Essentially, `\IfFileExist` does the following: (`#1` is your file, here `\IfStrEq...`)

```
\openin\@inputcheck#1\relax % open the file
\ifeof\@inputcheck          % did the file exist?
  File exists.
\else
  \@iffileonpath {#1}       % search in \input@path
    {File exists.}{File doesn't exist.}
\fi
```

The TeX primitive `\openin` takes the stream number `\@inputcheck` as its first argument, then expands as much as it can, grabbing characters for a file name until encountering a space (which it removes), or a non-expandable command. If the file name `#1` is made of characters, or expands to it, then the file name that `\openin` finds stops at the `\relax`, and `\IfFileExists` searches for the correct file. In your case, though, `\FileWithPath` expands from the left as much as TeX can, until reaching the unexpandable command `\let`. At this stage, no character has been encountered (as expected: nothing is typeset before `\IfStrEq` actually starts doing its tests), so `\openin` finds an empty file name.

But the whole `\FileWithPath` is still there, just expanded a little. As you expect, `\IfStrEq` typesets nothing, but the rest of the path is typeset. Then comes the `\ifeof` test: since your TeX distribution contains a file `.tex` (you can find its path by trying `\input\relax`), the empty `\openin` has opened that file in the stream `\@inputcheck`, thus the `\ifeof` test is true. The branch `File found` of the conditional is taken, making us think that everything has gone well.

So... how to fix that? Use an expandable string comparison, for instance. The package `expl3` (from the `l3kernel` bundle), which you are loading anyways through `xparse`, provides `\str_if_eq:xxTF` and `\str_if_eq:nnTF` which should suit your needs (the first expands its arguments as in an `\edef` before comparing them character by character; the second doesn't expand). To use such a "code" command, we need to go to the "Expl Syntax".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetTexFilePath}{m m m}
  {
    \str_if_eq:xxTF{#1}{SpecialValue}{}{}
    ../../../#1/#2/#3
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\FileWithPath{\GetTexFilePath{01}{02}{z}}%
\IfFileExists{\FileWithPath}{%
    \textcolor{red}{File \FileWithPath\ found.}%
}{%
    \textcolor{red}{File \FileWithPath\ not found.}%
}%
\end{document}
```

[Edited to replace `\NewDocumentCommand` by `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`: even though the former happens to work in this situation, in general, it defines a non-expandable command, and that will most often not expand, getting you back to the expansion problems described in the first part of this answer.] [Re-edited: Peter Grill mentions that `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` does not exist.]

Alternatively, you could use the slightly weird primitive `\pdfstrcmp` (or `\strcmp` in XeTeX, or, in LuaTeX, some command provided by Heiko?), which takes two arguments (expanding them as an `\edef`), and expands to -1, 0, or 1 depending on the lexicographical ordering of the strings, 0 if they're equal.

EDIT: Given [your further question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46323/2707), I think a simpler approach is to "compute" the full paths when defining `\FileWithPath` instead of defining `\FileWithPath` to compute the paths.  To do that, replace `\def\FileWithPath{...}` by a call to an assignment function `\defTeXFilePath` which performs some checks (expandable or not), and then decides what to store in `\FileWithPath`. Here I went for `\tl_if_eq:nnTF` instead of `\str_if_eq:xxTF`. Differences: "tl" instead of "str" means that we are comparing tokens, with their character code and category code, instead of simple strings (I think of that as colour versus black and white); "n" instead of "x" means that we perform no expansion. Feel free to change that to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defTeXFilePath}{m m m m}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF{#2}{SpecialValue}
      { \tl_set:Nn #1 { ../../../#2/#3/#4 } }
      { \tl_set:Nn #1 { ../../../#2/xxx#3/#4 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\defTeXFilePath{\FileWithPath}{01}{02}{z}%
%\show\FileWithPath % see that \FileWithPath contains no macro call.
\IfFileExists{\FileWithPath}{%
    \textcolor{red}{File \FileWithPath\ found.}%
}{%
    \textcolor{red}{File \FileWithPath\ not found.}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have resisted using the `expl3` syntax until now as it seems quote foreign to me. But in trying to adapt this solution, I assumed that that what goes in the trailing braces would after `{SpecialValue}` would be `{<true>}{<false>}`. So, I changed that line to `\str_if_eq:xxTF{#1}{SpecialValue}{\def\SomeMacroName{foo}}{\def\SomeMacroName{bar}}` and problem is back.  I want to use `SomeMacroName` to adjust the file name. Clearly there is something about this syntax that I am not understanding.  I had removed it from the original MWE as it was not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Again, `\def` is not expandable. You should use `\str_if_eq:xxTF{#1}{SpecialValue}{<file name for the special value>}{<normal file name>}`. You can't make any assignment within the file name.

Comment: I think you meant `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` instead of `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`, although I think the `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` is more consistent.  I'd change it, but not sure if this is due to a recent update to `xparse` or not.  Also follow up question: [Convert string to file name and use in \href](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48305/convert-string-to-file-name-and-use-in-href)

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't see what's wrong with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.  It should work fine, unless you've already defined that command elsewhere somehow.  In that case, of course, you need `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Comment: I seem am getting a `Undefined control sequence. l.6 \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetTexFilePath` when I run your first MWE.  But works fine if I replace it with `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you.  I had not tested the code, and it turns out `xparse` does not define the `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` as I had thought.