# Hyperref to expand macro in argument

Tags: hyperref, expansion

I am confused as to why the `edef` below does not get expanded in the link?

The `\GetTexFilePath` is from [Text being output when none should be](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42742/text-being-output-when-none-should-be), which is expandable, and the `\GetTexFilePathOld` is the older version which is not. Both yield identical results in this case.

I attempted various `\expandafter` magic but could not figure out the correct combination.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\GetTexFilePath}{m m m}{% Expandable version
    \str_if_eq:xxTF{#1}{SpecialValue}{#1/#2#3}{../#1/#2#3}%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\GetTexFilePathOld}{m m m}{%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{SpecialValue}{#1/#2#3}{../#1/#2#3}%
}%


\begin{document}
    \edef\FullExpandedFileName{\GetTexFilePath{foo}{bar}{.tex}}
    \href{run:\FullExpandedFileName}{\GetTexFilePath{foo}{bar}{}}
    %
    \edef\FullExpandedFileName{\GetTexFilePathOld{foo}{bar}{.tex}}
    \href{run:\FullExpandedFileName}{\GetTexFilePathOld{foo}{bar}{}}

    \edef\FullExpandedFileName{\GetTexFilePath{SpecialValue}{bar}{.tex}}
    \href{run:\FullExpandedFileName}{\GetTexFilePath{SpecialValue}{bar}{}}
    %
    \edef\FullExpandedFileName{\GetTexFilePathOld{SpecialValue}{bar}{.tex}}
    \href{run:\FullExpandedFileName}{\GetTexFilePathOld{SpecialValue}{bar}{}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commands created with `\NewDocumentCommand` are robust. You must use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` if you want an expandable version (see documentation of xparse). Or you can expand it once with

```
\expandafter\edef\expandafter\FullExpandedFileName\expandafter{\GetTexFilePath....
```

Comment: To expand protected commands within an `\edef`, it is simpler to do `\expandafter\empty\yourcommand`, so `\edef\FullExpandedFileName{\expandafter\empty\GetTeXFilePath...}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \grill_spval:n #1
  {
   \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { SpecialValue } { #1 } { ../#1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\PathHref{ m m m }
  {
   \exp_args:Nxx \href
     {
      run:\grill_spval:n {#1} / #2 #3
     }
     {
      \grill_spval:n {#1} / #2
     }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Now `\PathHref{foo}{bar}{.tex}` and `\PathHref{SpecialValue}{bar}{.tex}` should do what you want.

Notice that `\str_if_eq:xxTF` is not needed, as long as `#1` is a string; of course you might need `\str_if_eq:xxTF` if the first argument to `\PathHref` is to be expanded. The needed expansion is that of `\grill_spval:n`, that should be performed before `\href` comes into action: we obtain this by `\exp_args:Nxx`.