# Convert string to file name and use in \href

Tags: macros, expansion

I have a bunch of individual .tex files and want to be able to click on a link in one PDF file and have the appropriate PDF file open. These are small files, so don't really need to index into them, just have them open.

The file name to open can (in most cases) be determined from the descriptive link text -- algorithm below.  There will be a few cases where the file name can not be easily determined, so for that I want to also be able to manually specify it.  So, I define:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\CrossReference}{O{\NoValue} m}
```

where

```
#1 = optional file name (determined from #2 if not provided)
#2 = link text
```

I have the case where I manually specify the file name working in the MWE below.  However, since the file names can easily be determined, I would like to not have to provide it.  That is where `\ConvertToFileNameWithPath` is supposed to do its job.

### File Naming Algorithm:

If the file name is not specified, it is obtained form the given link text by:

1. Change all characters to lower case.
2. Replace any blanks with a dash.
3. Add the `.pdf` extension

### Notes:

1. For the MWE below to work (ie, to test that the links are click able), the file `equation-of-circle.pdf` must exist in the current directory.
2. Eventually, the macro `\ConvertToFileNameWithPath` will search for this file name in a particular list of directories -- will tackle that next.   So that will be step 4 in the above algorithm.
3. I did look at [the `xr` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr) and not sure it is appropriate for this case, mostly due to **Note 2** (there may be multiple files with the same name).

### References/Failed Attempts:

- I attempted to adapt Joseph Wright's answer at [Are there purely expandable variants of \MakeUppercase?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/are-there-purely-expandable-variants-of-makeuppercase), but was not successful. Also on the same question it mentions that `\tl_expandable_lowercase:n` is now available so that should certainly help. But not understanding `expl3`, I can't get much further than this.
- My start at this is based on Bruno Le Floch's answer to my question: [Text being output when none should be](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42742/text-being-output-when-none-should-be). Not that I was able to get very far with this, but perhaps this might help others figure this out.
- I also attempted to use a sequence of `\StrSubstitute{\Temp}{A}{A}[\Temp]`, `\StrSubstitute{\Temp}{B}{b}[\Temp]` to make the conversion, but this runs into expansion issues, and using `\tl_expandable_lowercase:n` should be easier.

### Code:

When the text above and below the `\hrule` is that same then this should be working: assuming of course you have `equation-of-circle.pdf` in the current directory, and can open it via lines 1 and 3.  Currently I can only open it via line 1 where I have manually specified the file name:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}


%\ExplSyntaxOn -- am guessing that this will be needed...
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\ConvertToFileNameWithPath}{o m}{%
    % This will eventually also locate a file in a given path 
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% file name not specified so need to figure it out
        % ????????? What goes here ???????
        ./#2.pdf% Need to convert #2 to a file name. ????????
    }{% We were given, the file name -- Even I can handle this case
        ./#1.pdf%
    }%
  }
%\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\CrossReference}{O{\NoValue} m}{%
    % #1 = optional file name (determined from #2 if not provided)
    % #2 = link text
    \edef\PdfFileName{\ConvertToFileNameWithPath[#1]{#2}}%
    \IfFileExists{\PdfFileName}{%
        \href{run:\PdfFileName}{#2}%
    }{%
        \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{#2}%
        \footnote{Unable to locate \PdfFileName}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
Manual References: \CrossReference[equation-of-circle]{Equation of Circle}%

Manual References: \CrossReference[non-existant-file]{Non Existant File}%

\medskip\hrule\medskip

Automatic References: \CrossReference{Equation of Circle}%

Automatic References: \CrossReference{Non Existant File}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the record (since you asked me to look on another thread), I agree with egreg and David that you don't need expandability.  `\tl_expandable_lowercase` is a rather specialized function, which should in most cases not be needed.  Also, it is very slow.  Actually, thinking about it again, we may want to generalize it, I need to think.

Comment: Useful Related Question: [Generate labels using `xstring` and `\Makelowercase`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49605/generate-labels-using-xstring-and-makelowercase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\CrossReference}{ o m }
  {
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}
     { \grill_convert_name:n { #2 } }
     { \tl_set:Nn \l_grill_file_name_tl { #1 } }
   \grill_set_link:n { #2 }
  }

\tl_new:N \l_grill_file_name_tl

\cs_new:Npn \grill_convert_name:n #1
  {
   \tl_to_lowercase:n { \tl_set:Nn \l_grill_file_name_tl { #1 } }
   \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_grill_file_name_tl { ~ } { - }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \grill_set_link:n #1
  {
   \file_if_exist:nTF { \l_grill_file_name_tl .pdf }
     {
      \group_begin:
      \cs_set:Npx\grill_temp:
        {
         \group_end:
         \exp_not:N \href{run\token_to_str:N : \l_grill_file_name_tl .pdf}{ #1 }
        }
      \grill_temp:
     }
     {
      \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{#1}
      \footnote{Unable~to~locate~\l_grill_file_name_tl}
     }
  }



\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\CrossReference{Abc Def}
\CrossReference[abc-def]{abc def}
\end{document}
```

The replacement of spaces by hyphens and the conversion to lowercase are easy.

Comment: Hmmm.. The output looks correct, but if I click on the link the file does not open for either the first or third link. For the code I posted it opened for the first link.  Also noticed that spaces are being stripped in the footnote -- perhaps that's a clue.

Comment: @PeterGrill You're right under both respects; the `\href` has to be inside an `\edef` and the colon must be "normalized". Spaces in text written when `\ExplSyntaxOn` must be denoted by `~`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine why you need the lowercasing expandable here (making the link won't be) so why not just

```
\def\foo#1#2{{%
\lccode`\ `\-%
\lowercase{#1{#2.pdf}}}}

\foo{\write20}{AB cd  / eFG}

\bye
```

which produces:

```
 tex lc
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (Web2C 2010)
(./lc.tex [1
ab-cd-/-efg.pdf
] )
```

Using this in LaTeX and adjusting it a bit to match your MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\textheight10\baselineskip
\usepackage{hyperref,color}

\def\xCrossReference#1#2{%
\IfFileExists{#1}{%
\href{#1}{#2}}{%
 \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{#2}%
 \footnote{Unable to locate #1}}}

\newcommand\CrossReference[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
     \bgroup\lccode`\ `\-\lowercase{\egroup
        \xCrossReference{#2.pdf}}{#2}%
  \else
   \xCrossReference{#1.pdf}{#2}%
   \fi}


\begin{document}
Manual References: \CrossReference[equation-of-circle]{Equation of Circle}%

Manual References: \CrossReference[non-existant-file]{Non Existant File}%

\medskip\hrule\medskip

Automatic References: \CrossReference{Equation of Circle}%

Automatic References: \CrossReference{Non Existant File}%
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think my rep has made you think that I know more than I do, but I am not able to figure out how to use this. When I replace `./#2.pdf` with `\foo{./}{#2}`, I get the error message: `Improper alphabetic constant. <to be read again> \discretionary`

Comment: @PeterGrill Odd. Try to replace `\-` by `\noexpand\-`.

Comment: Using `\def\foo#1#2{{%
\lccode'\ '\noexpand\-%
\lowercase{#1{#2.pdf}}}}` yields `Too many }'s.
\PdfFileName ...case {./{Equation of Circle.pdf}}}`. The nested back ticks were resulting in an issue in the display of the code here, so I replaced the back tick in the code with a `'` for display purposes here.

Comment: Ok, there was indeed an extra set of `{}` in the `\def`.  With this change, then lines 1 & 2 are correct (as they were in the original MWE), and clicking on line 1 does indeed open the file. However, lines 3 and 4 are incorrectly displayed in that extra text is shown, similar to problem outlined in [text being output when none should be](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42742/text-being-output-when-none-should-be), and clicking on the link on line 3 does _not_ open the PDF.  Also line 4 is displayed as if the file was found.

Comment: Yes the issue is exactly the sane as the previous question the `lccode` assignment is an assignment same as a `def` and so if you put them in an expansion context the arguments expand but the assignment doesn't happen. You don't put that in the edef or special, `foo` applies `#1` to '#2` after lowercasing the latter. So I use `\write20` for `#1` but you could use `\href`. I may expand the answer later (been out all day)

Comment: This still does not work for me.  I used `\foo{\href}{Equation of Circle}{Equation of Circle}` and it did not open the file. Also, not sure why I need to specify the args twice. Anyway, egreg's solution is working for me so can wait until you have more time.

Comment: Odd, it worked for me, I've updated the latex version to match your MWE.