# Spurious blank space when adding a member to a database within \foreach

Tags: spacing, datatool

The MWE adds blank space proportional to the maximum value of the `\foreach` iteration:

[image]

Why is this and how do I eliminate this additional space?

### Note:

- This problem seems similar to an earlier issue I had earlier in [Text being output when none should be](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42742/text-being-output-when-none-should-be), but I don't know how to resolve this issue.
- I am guessing this is some sort of expansion related issue as `\dtlexpandnewvalue` is required to get the correct output from the database.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\InitalizeDB}[1]{% 
    \DTLifdbexists{#1}%
        {\DTLcleardb{#1}}% DB exists, so just clear it
        {\DTLnewdb{#1}}%   DB does not exist, so create it
}%
\newcommand*{\AddMemberToDB}[3]{%
    % #1 = name of DB
    % #2 = db key to be used
    % #3 = member to be added to DB
    \dtlexpandnewvalue%
    \DTLnewrow{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%



\begin{document}
\InitalizeDB{MyDB}
\noindent
abc%
\foreach \x in {2,...,7} {%
    \AddMemberToDB{MyDB}{MyDBKey}{\x}%
}%
def

\bigskip\noindent
Database:\par
\DTLdisplaydb{MyDB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Question: [Spurious blank space when loading a datatool database](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/spurious-blank-space-when-loading-a-datatool-database/).

Comment: I've now fixed the bug (in v2.11) causing this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro `\@dtl@updatekeys` defines `\@defl@dogetprops` via an `\edef` and doesn't insert `%` at the end of the line, causing the unwanted skip:

```
\newcommand*{\@dtl@updatekeys}[3]{%
  \@sDTLifhaskey{#1}{#2}%
  {%
    \expandafter\dtlcolumnnum\expandafter
      =\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}\relax
    \edef\@dtl@dogetprops{\noexpand\@dtl@getprops
      {\noexpand\@dtl@key}{\noexpand\@dtl@type}%
      {\noexpand\@dtl@colhead}{\noexpand\@dtl@before}%
      {\noexpand\@dtl@after}{\the\csname dtlkeys@#1\endcsname}%
      {\number\dtlcolumnnum}}% <--------- inserted '%'
    \@dtl@dogetprops
    %...
}
```

Since `\@dtl@updatekeys` is quite large, issuing `\unskip` after you've added a member (either part of `\AddMemberToDB` or within the `\foreach`) solves the problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe

\newcommand*{\InitalizeDB}[1]{% 
    \DTLifdbexists{#1}%
        {\DTLcleardb{#1}}% DB exists, so just clear it
        {\DTLnewdb{#1}}%   DB does not exist, so create it
}%
\newcommand*{\AddMemberToDB}[3]{%
    % #1 = name of DB
    % #2 = db key to be used
    % #3 = member to be added to DB
    \dtlexpandnewvalue%
    \DTLnewrow{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%

\begin{document}
\InitalizeDB{MyDB}
\noindent
abc%
\foreach \x in {2,...,7} {%
    \AddMemberToDB{MyDB}{MyDBKey}{\x}\unskip%
}%
def

\bigskip\noindent
Database:\par
\DTLdisplaydb{MyDB}
\end{document}
```