# datatool repeat row

Tags: programming, loops, datatool

I intend to create a document where parts of the text are read from the entries of a `.csv` file using the package `datatool` (version 2012/09/25 v2.11., updated manually under debian).
Everything works fine as I want:

activities.csv:

```
"Role","Activity","NbActivity"
"Role 1","Activity A",1
"Role 1","Activity B",2
"Role 2","Activity C",3
```

read by the following `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb[]{activities}{activities.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{activities}
{\role=Role, \activity=Activity, \NbA=NbActivity}{
\role 
\activity \\
}
\end{document}
```

For the purpose of the document that I would like to create, rows of the database should be copied by the number indicated in the "NbActivity" column, resulting in something like that,...

```
"Role","Activity","NbActivity"
"Role 1","Activity A",1
"Role 1","Activity B",2
"Role 1","Activity B",2
"Role 2","Activity C",3
"Role 2","Activity C",3
"Role 2","Activity C",3
```

... in order to repeat those entries in the text as follows:

> Role 1  Activity A
>
> Role 1 Activity B
>
> Role 1 Activity B
>
> Role 2 Activity C
>
> Role 2 Activity C
>
> Role 2 Activity C

I tried to solve this by using `\DTLnewdbentry` and loops as suggested in [Repeat command n times?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/repeat-command-n-times), but just can't figure out how to do this. 
I am new to LaTeX programming/ macros, and would really appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Do you actually want the data duplicated in the DB, or do you want to just typeset the data that many times?

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you very much for your really quick answer! This is exactly what I needed: duplicates in the database so that the \DTLforeach produces the right outcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to duplicate the entries in the DB, I think the only way to do it is to user a new DB and create entries in the new DB as you step thru the original one.  Below is the **activities DB** (your original DB as read form the file), and the **activitiesExpanded DB** which contains the duplicated entries you desire:

[image]

### Notes:

- I used `\DTLforeach*` instead as we are in read only mode for the DB thru which we are stepping (and is faster).

### References:

- You should be aware of [Spurious blank space when adding a member to a database within \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70031/suprous-blank-space-adding-a-member-to-a-database-within-foreach) in case you see unexpected blank space in the output.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{pgffor}

%\usepackage{filecontents}% <-- commented out so file does not get overwritten
\begin{filecontents*}{activities.csv}
"Role","Activity","NbActivity"
"Role 1", "Activity A", 1
"Role 1", "Activity B", 2
"Role 2", "Activity C", 3
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{activities}{activities.csv}%  Read original DB
\DTLnewdb{activitiesExpanded}%           Initialize new DB

\noindent\textbf{activities DB:}
\DTLforeach*{activities}{%
        \role=Role, \activity=Activity, \NbA=NbActivity% % <-- This percent is important
    }{%
    \par\noindent\role\ \activity 
    \dtlexpandnewvalue
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\NbA} {% Duplicate entries as desired
        \DTLnewrow{activitiesExpanded}
        \DTLnewdbentry{activitiesExpanded}{Role}{\role}
        \DTLnewdbentry{activitiesExpanded}{Activity}{\activity}
        \DTLnewdbentry{activitiesExpanded}{NbActivity}{\NbA}
    }%
}

\bigskip
\noindent\textbf{ActivitiesExpanded DB:}
\DTLforeach*{activitiesExpanded}{%
        \role=Role, \activity=Activity, \NbA=NbActivity% <-- This percent is important
    }{%
    \par\noindent\role\ \activity
}

\end{document}
```